# Contact Form 7 - Uncaught TypeError: wpcf7.initForm is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugin-contact-form-7, contact, init

I updated to WordPress 5.7 and Contact Form 7 v5.4. The new version is not compatible anymore with a js file (line 6 "wpcf7.initForm"), that a previous developer wrote for our theme. Unfortunately I can't find a way to adapt the code so initForm get's recognized again. There are several suggestions with extra functions and I tried to copy them to different lines in the file, but the error won't disappear. Can someone please tell me, how I can correctly adapt the file to get rid of the error?

```
i.find(".wpcf7").each(function() {
            wpcf7.initForm(n(this).find(".wpcf7-form")[0]), this.addEventListener("wpcf7mailsent", function(n) {
                for (var t = null, e = n.detail.inputs, i = 0; i < e.length; i++)
                    if ("contact-email" === e[i].name) {
                        t = e[i].value;
                        break
                    }
```

Every help is appreciated.

**Edit:** If someone is facing the same issue: the solution is to replace `wpcf7.initForm($form);` with `wpcf7.init($form[0]);`. Thanks to Jules Colle at this point for the hint!